# How to validate the output of grep in Jenkinsfile groovy

Tags: groovy, grep, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a command to retrieve the latest commit message in git and then do a grep to see if it contains certain string and then use that as a condition but getting errors.

```html
def commitmsg = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -1  --pretty='%s' | grep Merge").trim()

if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'release' && commitmsg == 'Merge')
{
..........
}
```

How do i get this to work? I just want that if the output of

```html
git log -1  --pretty='%s'
```

contains the string Merge then i can use it under if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.

```html
def commitmsg = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git log -1  --pretty='%s'").trim()

if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'release' && commitmsg.contains("Merge pull request") == true)
{
....
}
```